# Springboot war for multiple container

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Springboot war production by maven is documented at [spring-doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html).
The documentation provides way to do for jboss and weblogic differently.

For jboss :

- servlet path = /*

For Weblogic :

- implements WebApplicationInitializer

If i want to target the war for weblogic and jboss, how to achieved

- maven build produced two war for each container OR
- make the single war use for both container.

Comment: A war is a war regardless of the container. The servlet-path is only for an executable jar/war not for deploying a war to a container. When deploying to a container you need a `WebApplicationInitializer` to be precise you must extend the `SpringBootServletInitializer`.